# Upload pandas dataframe to a temporary table in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to upload a dataframe to a temporary table (using pandas to_sql method) in SQL Server but having problems. I am able to upload dataframes to 'normal' tables in SQL fine.

The error I get is below & it tells me that a temporary table called #d already exists.

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named '#d' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")
> [SQL:
> CREATE TABLE [#d] (

However if I run the DROP TABLE #d (in my code below) I get the error below & I do have permissions to create and drop tables,

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot drop the table '#d', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (3701) (SQLExecDirectW)")
> [SQL: DROP TABLE #d]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

The errors seem conflicting to me

My code is below.

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
cnxn = engine.connect()


# q = """DROP TABLE #d"""
# cnxn.execute(q)   

q = """ 
CREATE TABLE #d(id int, 
time_stamp datetime,
pressure float)
"""
cnxn.execute(q)    

# upload data into temp table
df.to_sql('#d', cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Maybe the "object named '#d'" is not a table?

Comment: The temp table `#d` doesn't exist in your database, it exists in tempdb. What happens if you try `df.to_sql('tempdb..#d', cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)`? Note that there are two period characters `..` between `tempdb` and `#d`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks, that helps. However I am running an example and put a break point in see that my dataframe has only 13 rows but in the temp table 117 rows have been uploaded. Bit confused as to why

Comment: update, if I change if_exists='append' to 'replace' then only 13 rows get uploaded which is correct. I am confused though why 'append' seems to be uploading the dataframe multiple times, with the break point I can see the temp table doesn't exist before the dataframe is uploaded